# syncdb doesn't create table models

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a web application with Django framework. I have this structure :

- project

  - web_app

    - models

      - models.py
  - rwtool

    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py

I defined my models in `models.py` file. In my settings file I added this line `project.web_app` in  `INSTALLED_APPS`. When I did

```
python mange.py syncdb
```

the models are not created. To create them I must add the `project.web_app.models` to my settings file. I have looked to others project and they don't do like this and it works.  Is it correct what I'm doing?

Comment: so you have models.py module inside models folder?

Comment: yes that's right. Sorry I haven't figured how to print the folder structure

Comment: i think u created a folder called models.. there is no need of folder called models. keep model.py in web_app folder then syncdb..

Comment: But what i want this structure?

Comment: no . u cannot use such structure in django . why need a different folder. for only onefile.. we use larger applications  using django. still u can have one model.py for an app

Comment: why do you need this structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**models.py** should be under your app folder (in your case "**web_app**").

If you want to separate your models then you have to turn models folder into a python package, in this case add an `__init__.py` in that folder and make sure that in the init file your models are accessible to the outside world at the path "**web_app.models.ModelName**".

So, solution 1 (standard Django approach):

- project

  - web_app
  - models.py

Solution 2:

- project

  - web_app
  - models

    - `__init__.py`
    - ModelOne.py
    - ModelTwo.py...

the `__init__.py` will contains something like:

```
from .ModelOne import ModelOne
from .ModelTwo import ModelTwo
```

The approach N2 can be also used for views and other stuff too ;)

Answer (score 0):

First add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` , and then run

```
python manage.py inspectdb > somefile.txt
```

You can get quickly check out if your database structure is matching your django models.

If `python manage.py inspectdb > somefile.txt` not created any structure, then make sure that your app is added to  to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Yes if i add `project.web_app.models` but not when I add `project.web_app`